# c++ stdout flushes stream unexpectedly

Tags: c++, visual-studio, iostream

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        cout << "Hello\n";
    }

    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(2000));

    cout << "2 seconds have passed" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In my code, I didn't call any `std::flush` or `std::endl`, but the hello's are printed before the 2 seconds delay. I am expecting to print all the hello's after the 2 seconds delay, but it didn't. My code runs like this:

```
Hello
Hello
.
.
.
Hello
Hello
(after 2 seconds)
2 seconds have passed
[terminated]
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: the stream is allowed to flush whenever it wants to

Comment: Your code does the printing before the delay. What you got is exactly what I would expect. If you expected the printing to run during the delay, you would need to launch a separate thread, one to print, and the other to wait.

Comment: @Logicrat OP expects everything to be printed in one go after the delay, being under assumption that stream doesn't flush unless you request it explicitly.

Comment: If you want to output hello after 2s delay, you should put `this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(2000));` before the for loop.

Comment: If you find the solution, you could click '✔' to mark it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See also [stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you're writing more output than a typical file buffer will hold, so you'd almost always expect at least *some* of the output to show up before the sleep.

Second, you're doing a lot of separate output calls, so if `cout` is unit-buffered, each one is going to be flushed immediately.

Third, you're writing a new-line at the end of each item, so if `cout` is line-buffered, (yup) each one is going to be flushed immediately.

So, if you want a *better* chance of seeing at least some of the output showing up after the sleep ends, turn off unit buffering and get rid of the new-lines:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << nounitbuf;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        cout << "Hello";
    }
    // display something different to make it easier for user to see
    // whether all output showed up before sleep or not.
    cout << "..."; 

    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(2000));

    cout << "2 seconds have passed" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But even with this, there's no guarantee the behavior will change. Rather the contrary, most implementations go to some pain to assure that output written to the console shows up as promptly as possible, so even when you take steps toward delaying it, it'll still probably show up before the sleep. But this might improve your chances a little bit anyway.